# Dynamically adjust value based on length of variable in Jinja2

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have the following code for writing text to a file. This works when the inventory_hostname is always the same length.

```
{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ "%-69s" | format(file['path'] | replace('E:', '') | replace('\\','/') | truncate(63,true,'')) }}moretext
```

I want to set the length of the section of text based on the length of inventory_hostname. Something like this.

```
{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ "%-{{ 75 - inventory_hostname|length }}s" | format(file['path'] | replace('E:', '') | replace('\\','/') | truncate(63,true,'')) }}moretext
```

I need the results to always line up on a particular column.

For example:

```
hostname1programfiles/program/dll   moretext
host1programfiles/program/note      moretext
hostnameisreallylong/programfile/p  moretext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ljust() to adjust the size of strings

```py
>>> 'hello'.ljust(20))[0:20]
'hello               '
>>> 'hello world'.ljust(20))[0:20]
'hello world         '
>>> 'hello world this is a long text'.ljust(20)[0:20]
'hello world this is '
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust

Comment: The problem with that is it only works on a single variable in Jinja2 from what I can tell. I need a method that can apply that to two variables, or I need a way in Jinja2 to combine variables. When the length of inventory_hostname changes, it pushes "moretext" into a different column. I need the whole value of inventory_hostname and I need to truncate the file['path'] so that regardless of where it starts moretext occurs on the same column.

Comment: Update: I used "set" to create a variable using string concatenation in Jinja2. That worked. Thank you!